# While mysqli_fetch_array in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can someone help me how to convert this php query into Codeigniter standard? Can while statement use in CI?

This is my code that I already tried to converted into CI:

**Model**

```
function getStudents(){
    $this->db->select('id, name');
    $this->db->get('students');
}
```

**Controller**

```
$id = array();
$name = array();

$query = $this->md_students->getStudents();

while ($result = $query->result_array()) {
       array_push($id, $result[0]);
       array_push($name, $result[1]);
}
```

And this is the original code:

```
$id = array();
$name = array();

$query = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT student_id, student_name FROM students');

    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
           array_push($id, $result[0]);
           array_push($name, $result[1]);
    }
```

I know there's some duplicate on this question, I already tried that solutions but that didn't works for me.

Comment: Which kind of "standard" are you looking for? What's the problem with the given code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Model**

```
    function getStudents(){
      $sql = 'SELECT student_id, student_name FROM students';
      $qry = $this->db->query($sql);
      return $qry->result_array(); //It will return an array of result
    }
```

**Controller**

```
    $id = array(); //array initialization
    $name = array();

    $student_list = $this->md_students->getStudents(); //call a function in model

    foreach ($student_list as $student) {
      array_push($id, $student['student_id'];
      array_push($name, $student['student_name];
    }
```